# How to make a taxonomy using shortcode

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

i want to make a taxonomy using shortcode i dont want to used any plugin i use this code in my plugin can someone help me

```
// create a new taxonomy
register_taxonomy(
  'Category',
  'projects',
  array(
    'labels' => array(
      //'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
      'name' => __('Skills'),
      'singular_name' => __('skills'),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Skill'),
      'update_item' => __('Update Skill'),
      'new_item_name' => __('New Skill Name'),
      'all_items' => __('All Skill Name'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Skill'),
      'search_items' => __('Seacrh Skill Name'),
      'popular_items' => __('Popular Skill'),
      'separate_items_with_comments' => __('Separate Items With Comments'),
      'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add Or Remove Items'),
      'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose From Most Used'),
    ),
    'public' => TRUE,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'skills',
      'with_front' => TRUE
    ),
    'hierarchical' => TRUE,
  )
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly indent your code. I would recommend you to follow some specific code styling, such as the one used by Wordpress, so that other people can read your code easier and be able to co-operate on that. Good luck!

Comment: can you preffer me code styling of wordpress ?